# Iterated global variable not triggering == condition

Tags: python, scope, global

I have tried placing the `turn = 0` inside the `play` function
I have read several similar questions on Stackoverflow, and attempted to put `global turn` inside and outside of my function. These did not throw errors, but also did not result in a turn limit.  Why? Any ideas on how to fix this?

My gut says that because I've set the variable `turn` to `global` I'm going to keep referencing `turn=0` for it's value because that's set outside the function, but since it will run iterating numbers as you take turns, I'm wrong.

Here's my code:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Incredibly Simple Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row #erase after testing
print ship_col

global turn

def play(guess_row,guess_col):
  global turn
  if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
  else:
    if turn == 4:
        print "Game Over"
    if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
        print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
    elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
        print "You guessed that one already."
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        print_board(board)
        print "Guess again:"
    print "Turn ",turn,":"
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
    turn += 1
    play(guess_row,guess_col)  


turn=0
guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))      
play(guess_row,guess_col)
```

Here's the original error when I didn't use global:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "python", line 51, in <module>
 File "python", line 30, in play
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'turn' referenced before assignment
```

NB I want to take the advice not to use `global` but haven't figured out an alternative yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that keeps track of turn by an extra variable on the recursive play() function.  Note I also added a return for you so that the game can end on a Game Over. :)

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Incredibly Simple Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row #erase after testing
print ship_col


def play(guess_row,guess_col, turn):
  if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
  else:
    if turn == 4:
        print "Game Over"
        return
    if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
        print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
    elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
        print "You guessed that one already."
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        print_board(board)
        print "Guess again:"
    print "Turn ",turn,":"
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
    play(guess_row,guess_col, turn + 1)


guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
play(guess_row,guess_col, 0)
```

Comment: So you can pass a variable in through the function call, and iterate it by passing it +1 IN the function (re)call? Brilliant!

Comment: Sweet, no problem.  Your method can also work, but you define global turn twice.  Take out the first "global turn" in your code and you should be good to go (Remember to also add that return statement after the Game Over).

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had! I tried taking out the `global turn` before the function, I could still play many turns. When I moved it to before the function, it generated a similar error to before. :s